# Warhammer fantasy role play 3rd tutorial

Tags: wfrp-3e

Is there a good set of resources to summarise the rules without the fluff.

I am finding it difficult to take in all the rules and get a game going. My group won't want to listen to me read everything and would rather play and learn as they go.

Comment: Thankfully WFRP is quite easy to learn, and I imagine that you can do a tutorial session of the game the way most video games do.  Often times, you can skip most of the fluff and get to the mechanics towards the end of a paragraph.  Is there a specific aspect of the game that is causing you trouble?

Comment: its new so i'm overwhelmed. I think a concise guide to building a dice pool would be good. a lot of the info on the cards looks the same eg. 2 banes seems to always have the same effect. also when do critical hits actually happen? ...these should probably be separate questions. I should write them up separately.

Comment: @Peter Your best bet is to just start asking specific questions like the ones in your comment. It's a lot easier for us to answer a focused question, and more efficient too... We can skip over the stuff you already get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find it, the preview adventure shipped to stores had just such summaries in it.